# How to chain firebase observables using redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, rxjs, redux-saga

I've recently made the move from ionic/angular2/Rxjs to React/React Native/Redux-sagas. I'm porting over my app from ionic to react native and have really enjoyed the process. One thing, however, I have really struggled with is using firebase in react native via redux sagas. I can do simple requests however I would like to chain three requests and get the return value as an JSON object. Currently I have this :

```
    export const getTuteeUID = state => state.login.username;

function* getMemberProfiles(UID) {
  try {
    const memberObject = yield call(get, 'userProfile', UID);
    return memberObject;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function* getLatestConversation(grpID) {
  try {
    const opts = newOpts();
    const refLatestConvo = firebase
      .database()
      .ref('conversations')
      .child(`${grpID}`)
      .orderByChild('createdAt')
      .limitToLast(1);
    yield call([refLatestConvo, refLatestConvo.on], 'value', opts.handler);
    while (true) {
      const { data } = yield take(opts);
      if (data.val()) {
        return data.val()[data._childKeys[0]];
      }
      return null;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export function* getChatGroupObject(grpID, tuteeUID) {
  try {
    const groupObject = yield call(get, 'groups', grpID);
    const memberProfiles = yield Object.keys(groupObject.members)
      .filter(mem => mem !== tuteeUID)
      .map(memUID => call(getMemberProfiles, memUID));
    const latestConversation = yield call(getLatestConversation, grpID);
    return { ...groupObject, memberProfiles, key: grpID, latestConversation };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

/**
 *
 * @return {Generator} []
 */
export function* fetchChatGroups() {
  try {
    const opts = newOpts();
    const tuteeUID = yield select(getTuteeUID);
    const refGrpIDs = firebase.database().ref('userProfile').child(`${tuteeUID}/groups`);
    const snapGrpIDs = yield call([refGrpIDs, refGrpIDs.once], 'value', opts.handler);
    if (snapGrpIDs.val()) {
      const groupObject = yield Object.keys(snapGrpIDs.val()).map(grpID =>
        call(getChatGroupObject, grpID, tuteeUID),
      );
      yield put(ChatAction.chatGroupsReceived(groupObject));
    } else {
      ChatAction.chatGroupsReceived([]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Now this works and returns the correct object, however if the latest conversation in the array changes the object won't update. How can I get this to continue updating? Another thing is if I were to put this in a while(true) loop, is there a way to unsubscribe from the observable? In rxjs this used to be super easy to do.

Comment: I'm not experienced with this, but I'd like to share some thoughts. In your current code are you able to check if the latest conversation changed? If so, do you think using a `setState()` to trigger a re rendering would help you? I guess if your component rerenders your logic will be run again with the updated data. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: For your second question, if I understood correctly, you can't avoid firebase of listening to changes in a specific node, for example, if you are using `ref('Users/')` you can't avoid listening to 'Users/X' changes. What you can do in this case is convert your snapshot.val() to array (if it doesn't return an array by default) and `.filter()` it to work only with the data you want to.
Sorry if I understood your questions wrong.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I think you have misunderstood the question. I'm using redux sagas to emit values if the conversation has changed, I'm not doing this within the component. Also you can cancel a subscription to a firebase ref simply by unsubscribing, but I was wondering what best practice is for saga channels.